# Using mtpfs and adb with Nexus 7 on Android 4.2.1

Tags: android

Stock, out the box, they both worked. But after the updates I can't access the internal storage with mtpfs and the device isn't listed when I used 'adb devices'. I've searched around but everything I found worked only when on 4.2. I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 on my computer. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the hardware ID's to your udev rules?

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up

Comment: Stupid question: Are you sure you're using the cable that came with the phone? My Galaxy Nexus is finicky about what cables it will actually charge and connect through.  If the 7 isn't showing that it's charging, or if you're not seeing anything in dmesg when you plug it in, this might be the issue.

Comment: I am using the cable that came with the device.